# Gin-gonic Error : listen tcp: lookup addr on : no such host

Tags: go, go-gin

```
Machine : Debian 10 running on Windows 10 - Hypervisor 
Go Ver  : go1.14.4
Gin-gonic Version : v1.6.3
```

While running program getting below error !. Tried many solution found in net but no luck( those are not related directly to `gin-gonic`)

```
$ go run main.go
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Creating an Engine instance with the Logger and Recovery middleware already attached.

[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
 - using env:   export GIN_MODE=release
 - using code:  gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on addr:8080
[GIN-debug] [ERROR] listen tcp: lookup addr on 192.168.43.1:53: no such host
Calling okay!!!
```

`main` program calling function `StartApplicaton` in `application.go`

```
    $ cat app/application.go
    package app

    import(  "fmt"
            "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    )

var (
        router = gin.Default()
)

//StartApplicaiton will call from main
func StartApplicaton() {
        mapUrls()
        router.Run("addr:8080")
        fmt.Println("Calling okay!!!")
}
```

Including `/etc/resolve.conf` and `/etc/hosts` file for reference

```
$cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.43.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8


$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       debian
192.168.43.1    wifirtr #addded to check

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 0):

`router.Run("addr:8080")` changed to `router.Run(":8081")` solved my issue!!, 
stillI am not sure why it solved my issue ( need to dig later)

**Edit** : Later Identified that `addr` part was not in code , it was a help text showing by the IDE. I misunderstood while following an online tutorial.

[image]